# SenchaTouch onItemDisclosure 2 icons

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a list and I want have two icons per line using `onItemDisclosure`. How can I do that?

Comment: it is possible but not easy. In short you have to extend class http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List and/or http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.element.List

Comment: @olegtaranenko please post your comment as an answer so the question my be closed properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to implement **onItemDisclousre()** on two icons but probably this will help you.

In the following example i have put an image on every **itemlist** and functionality is provided on  **itemtap event**. This will serve the purpose of doing multiple tasks with single **itemlist.**

```
//demo.js

Ext.define("Stackoverflow.view.demo", {
extend: "Ext.Container",
requires:"Ext.dataview.List",
alias: "widget.demo",

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    items: [
    {
        xtype: "list",
        store: "store",
        itemId:"samplelist",
        loadingText: "Loading Notes...",
        emptyText: "<div class=\"notes-list-empty-text\">No notes found.</div>",
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        itemTpl:"<div class='x-button related-btn' btnType='related' style='border: none; background: url(\"a.png\") no-repeat;'></div>"+
                   "<div class=\"list-item-title\">{title}</div>"
        grouped: true
    }

    ],
    listeners:
    [
            {
            delegate: "#samplelist",
            event: "disclose",
            fn: "onDiscloseTap"
        }
    ]
},    
onDiscloseTap: function (list, record, target, index, evt, options) {

    this.fireEvent('ondisclosuretap', this, record);
}
});
```

// Democontrol.js

```
  Ext.define("Stackoverflow.controller.Democontrol", {
  extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
    refs: {
        // We're going to lookup our views by xtype.
        Demo: "demo", 
        Demo1: "demo list",
          },
    control: {
        Demo: { 
               ondisclosuretap: "Disclosure", 
         },
        Demo1: { 

             itemtap:"imagetap" 

        }

    }
},

 Disclosure: function (list, record,target,index,e,obj) {
   Ext.Msg.alert('','Disclosure Tap');

},

  imagetap: function (dataview,index,list,record, tar, obj) { 
     tappedItem = tar.getTarget('div.x-button');
    btntype = tappedItem.getAttribute('btnType');
    if(btntype == 'related')
    {
    Ext.Msg.alert('','Image/Icon Tap');
    }
},

// Base Class functions.
launch: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);

 },
init: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);

}
});
```

//app.css

```
 .related-btn
   {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.85em;
      right: 2.50em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   }
```

Hope this will help you.
bye.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manually adding a disclosure icon inside of itemTpl on your list items. Add this inside of your view:

```
     {
            xtype: 'list',
            onItemDisclosure: true,
            cls: 'my-list-cls',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div class="x-list x-list-disclosure check-mark" style="right: 48px"></div>'                 
            ]
        }
```

Notice that the `div` inside of `itemTpl` has the CSS class "x-list x-list-disclosure check-mark". I set `style="right: 48px"` because I want this icon to appear on the left side of the regular disclosure icon (the one with the right arrow) and this rule leaves enough room on the right to show the arrow icon.

Then, in your app.scss, add:

```
.my-list-cls {
  .x-list.check-mark.x-list-disclosure:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '3';
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
  }
}
```

This controls the styling for your new disclosure icon.
By setting `content: '3';`, you are changing the icon from the default right arrow to a checkmark. (See all of the available icons here: [Pictos fonts](http://pictos.cc/classic/font)).

The result:
[image: Sencha Touch list]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not easy. In short you have to extend class [Ext.dataview.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) and/or [Ext.dataview.element.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.element.List).